# Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know what this warning is referring to and how I would go about resolving it?

```
 Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters are deprecated, and may be blocked in M60, around August 2017. Please remove newlines from places like element attribute values in order to continue loading those resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

I am getting above description in `console`

I am trying to use pass url in `$.getJSON` method. i am getting url in alert box but it can't goes to controller class.

My code here:

```
function LoginSucessInfo( result )
{       
    var id = "6546767576657";       
    url =  "/logindetails?id="+id+"&result="+result;
    alert(url);
    $.getJSON(url, function(data1){
        alert("--");
    });     
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert`. See if there are any newline characters in `aadhaar` or `result`.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 7):

There might be newline characters or HTML or whitespace in `result`. Sanitize `result` using encodeURIComponent

```
...
result = encodeURIComponent(result);
url =  "/logindetails?id="+id+"&result="+result;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you modify your URL variable to something like the one I suggested below it will solve the problem:

```
url = encodeURI("/logindetails?id="+id+"&result="+result;);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add your data to variables then put them in your data place for ex:
that was my problem

```
<a  href="<?php if($page == $number_of_pages ){echo '#';}else{ echo "?page=".$page+=1 ."&text="."$searchWord";} ?>"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
```

---

```
<a  href="<?php if($page == $number_of_pages ){echo '#';}else{ **$next=$page+1**;echo "?page=".**$next** ."&text="."$searchWord";} ?>"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
```

And I converted like that it is actually working now with out any Errors :)