# Chrome giving Deprecation error? Fetching data from an API endpoint not working

Tags: java, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm currently building a search utility using Github's API that takes in a search query, (for example, the name 'Brian'), validates the input, then displays a list of search results relevant to the query. My code/logic looks fine:

```
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');

// function that takes user's input after a quick validation test
// returned value is the user's input, which is stored in the variable 'query'
let query = () => {
    // validation code
    let input = document.getElementById('search').value;
    
    if(input.length < 3){
        alert("Please enter more than two characters.");
    }
    return input;
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', query);


//function that retrieves data from API endpoint by concatenating API url with query variable
function getData(){

    
    // template literal
    fetch(`https://github.uconn.edu/api/v3/search/users?q=${query}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    // catch is a callback function for when request fails
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}


searchBtn.addEventListener('click', getData);
```

but for some reason I am getting the following error from my Chrome console:

> [Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.

I've tried using `encodeURIComponent()` as mentioned in this [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203638/resource-requests-whose-urls-contain-raw-newline-characters-are-deprecated-in-jq). There doesn't seem to be much info online about this particular error, or an explanation of what it means.

The link to my project: https://github.uconn.edu/pages/ssw19002/dmd-3475/Week-10/github-search/github.html

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see where you do anything with the returned value from your `query()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add both functions as event listeners, because for one, the `query()` function isn't being called, nor the output assigned to a variable. Also, if you just define it as a function, you can call that function from the other function, which you can add as a listener.

```
// function that takes user's input after a quick validation test  
// returned value is the user's input

function query() {
    // validation code
    const input = document.getElementById('search').value;
    
    if(input.length < 3){
        alert("Please enter more than two characters.");
        return; // Added this so that we're not returning a value that's too short
    }
    return input;
}

// function that retrieves data from API endpoint by concatenating API url with query variable
function getData(){

    const qParam = query();
    if( !qParam ) return; // if there's no valid query value, no need to try to call the API
    
    fetch(`https://github.uconn.edu/api/v3/search/users?q=${qParam}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    // catch is a callback function for when request fails
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', getData);
```